# Is it possible to silver solder a reliable grounding connection to a stainless steel ultrasonic cleaner tank?

Tags: metallurgy, welding, ultrasound, brazing

My ultrasonic cleaner has a stainless steel tank with a threaded grounding stud for fastening a mains earth wire. I tried to tighten nut that fastens the ground terminal to the stud, but the stud sheared cleanly off the tank.  It appears it was either spot welded, soldered or brazed on.

Unfortunately, I can't think of another way to reliably ground the tank. I'm considering silver soldering or brazing the stud back on, but I fear a couple of issues:

1. The brazing or soldering material could corrode over time since they're likely to be dissimilar metals.
2. The ultrasonic cleaning vibration could compromise the resulting joint over time leading to failure.

Should I be concerned with any of these issues? Is there a better alternative to these methods?

Comment: is there a free lip you could drill and bolt to? A picture may help otherwise we are just guessing....